# Get the badge value from payload

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i try to get the value of badge from payload (in payload: badge = 1;) but the value looks more like a memory address:

```
int badgeValue = (int)[notification objectForKey:@"badge"];
NSLog(@"Value of badge(middle) is : %d", badgeValue);
Value of badge(middle) is : 392626528 (this is from console)
```

Do you have some ideas why? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are casting an object (`NSNumber`) to an `int`. All this does is put the memory reference of the object into the int.

What you need is something like this...

```
NSNumber *badgeValue = [notification objectForKey:@"badge"];
NSLog(@"Value of badge(middle) is : %@", badgeValue);
```

If you want to use an `int` **(note, you shouldn't use `int` you should use `NSInteger`)** then something like this...

```
NSInteger badgeValue = [[notification objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];
NSLog(@"Value of badge(middle) is : %ld", (long)badgeValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, i already modified the code. Definitely a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert an `NSNumber` object to an `int`, you should be using the `intValue` selector:

```
int badgeValue = [[notification objectForKey:@"badge"] intValue];
```

When you cast it using just `(int)`, you are retrieving the integer representation of the object pointer (as you suspected).